# Importing API from external site to Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, jekyll

We have an api that we use currently in our site.  We are moving everything over to Drupal 9 as a decoupled site.  We need to import the current api (https://www.healthcare.gov/api/glossary.json) that we use to allow content editors to retrieve this information when creating content. Is there a simple way to pull the api into the site for users to do this? Currently we are using Jekyll.

Steps taken so far:

Using the Feeds module, we have created a Feed that has that points to the link above. How do we implement this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You need Services module to provides some API : check this out https://www.drupal.org/project/services , but you'll need to code some lines

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on feed importer in D9 to pull JSON response from external API and create/update content then you can use [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex)

Use jsonpath for parser settings in feed importer mapping, allow json extension in feed fetcher. To check correct keys for mapping try https://jsonpath.com/ while you are adding mapping in feed importer.
$.* can be set in context settings on mapping page.